# Error setting up Xdebug with Xampp (Windows 7) - server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Tags: php, apache, xampp, xdebug

I have been trying to setup Xdebug to work with Xampp but it gives me an error loading the file.

**Error log:**

```
[Wed Mar 25 23:00:50.218514 2015] [core:warn] [pid 4144:tid 248] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?

Failed loading C:\Users\tara\workspace\php_xdebug-2.3.2-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Wed Mar 25 23:00:50.438521 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4144:tid 248] AH00455: Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.6.3 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Wed Mar 25 23:00:50.438521 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4144:tid 248] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul 17 2014 11:50:08

[Wed Mar 25 23:00:50.438521 2015] [core:notice] [pid 4144:tid 248] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'

[Wed Mar 25 23:00:50.440521 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4144:tid 248] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5964

[Wed Mar 25 23:00:50.964551 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 5964:tid 260] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

This is what I have in my **php.ini file:**

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\Users\tara\workspace\php_xdebug-2.3.2-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll" 
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
```

Answer (score 3):

I ended up finding out that I had the wrong version of XDebug installed.  I installed the newest one for my version of Windows and looked at the TS vs not TS) + PHP, but they have a custom installer that told me to go with a slightly older version and then it worked!  Here's the site:
http://xdebug.org/wizard.php

After this fix, I still had an error with the session not starting when I ran Eclipse (it would freeze at the load forever and say it was waiting for the XDebug session).  I fixed that by adding the following line to my php.ini file:

```
xdebug.idekey=ECLIPSE_DBGP
```

Comment: Okay. Thats just a really easy solution. Works like a charme. Thx!